# mouseover in js throws undefined error

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

In the following code snippet, when i try to add the `mouseover` functionality for the svg it throws `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on mouseover`.

```
svg.selectAll(".bar1")
    .data(clensedData)
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
      return i / clensedData.length * 10;
    })
    .duration(500)
    .attr("class", "bar1")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return x(d.City)
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return y(d.Cases);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
      return height - y(d.Cases);
    })
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {

      if (d.diff == max_of_array)
        return "green";

      if (d.diff == min_arr)
        return "red";
      else
        return "orange";
    })              
    .on("mouseover", function () {
});
```

Any ideas? ps: new to js

Comment: Please put your svg code.

Comment: Can you please put the code in a JSFiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: its tied to my application which cant be separated to be put in jsfiddle :( but the exception happens only with the on method in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to add the onclick where i was creating the svg and not the place i was appending it.. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why moving the click handler fixed your issue is that before you were not calling `.on('click', function(){})` on a D3 selection, but instead on a D3 **transition** which `.transition()` was returning.

I'm guessing you moved it before the `transition()` call. In most cases the usual pattern is to have the `transition()`, `duration()` and its `attr()`s as the last part of the function chain.

Answer (score 0):

In your code ")" is missing. Check last line of your code